# Create a hyperlink that is dynamic

Tags: excel

In Excel 2010
On the same worksheet

I want to be able to click on Cell # A3

that click has it jump to # A8 (in the same worksheet).

and then be able to insert a row at # A6,

and still have A3 automatically jump linked to #A8

My apologies, my searches do not seem to point me to a solution.  If it is there just point me there and I will see what my limited Excel skills will allow me to learn.  The hardest part is learning the terminology to discover what my solution will be.  FYI - I have never done a "VBA' solution in my past so that part will be a little difficult for me to understand, but I can try.

I was hoping the 'Edit Hyperlink' window's 'Type the cell reference' field would have allowed for $ character to keep the 'mapped' cell as dynamic.

Comment: Using Insert>Hyperlink this is the default behavior: if I link to A8 then that link will always go to A8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 'DEFINED NAME' in hyperlink. Use name box to create the defined name for your 'to be' hyperlinked cell and use that defined name to link. More step by step details is available [here](http://sivajankan.blogspot.com/2015/04/excel-hyperlink-tying-to-cell.html)

Comment: I included the detailed answer below

Answer (score 0):

In cell **A3** enter the formula:

```
=HYPERLINK("#A8","A8")
```

and as Tim Williams points out, that is where it will always go.

If, however, you wanted the destination to "move" as **A8** moves, you would assign a *Name* to the destination

Answer (score -1):

Well I have a friend that found my answer that worked

One liner:
  The technique is 'define the name' for the cell to be linked and use that 'defined name' in hyper link.

Ref:
http://sivajankan.blogspot.com/2015/04/excel-hyperlink-tying-to-cell.html

Before going on step by step, please find what is 'Name Box'.

Name box:

The left most cell in 'Formula bar' is the Name Box. When you hover the Name Box cell, it shows 'Enter a name for a cell range, or select a named range from the list' [in MSOffice 2013]

Step by Step:

Create the Defined Name:
Select the cell you want to be hyperlinked (to be jumped to). In the 'Name Box' [check the image above], enter a 'reference' name and press return key. [Assumed 'Reference1' for our example case]
Use the Defined Name in Hyperlink
Go to the cell where you want to place the hyperlink (to be jumped from), right click and click on 'Hyperlink' from the menu
In the 'Insert Hyperlink' popup window, in 'Anchor' ['Link to' for older version] section, click on 'locate'; which opens another popup window
In the 'Select Place in Document' popup, expand the 'Defined Names' by clicking the small triangle [or + icon] next to it [make the triangle point down, or change + to -, by clicking], and select the reference you made in step 2. [Our example 'Reference1']

Now your hyperlink pointed to the reference; so inserting or deleting any rows or columns won't affect your hyperlink pointing cell location.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I added the essential parts